# How to use set_clip_path() with multiple polygons?

Tags: python, matplotlib, clip

I'm trying to **clip** a cloud of points by **several polygons**, but I don't know if this is possible with `plt.axis.set_clip_path()`.

Since `set_clip_path()` requires a *Path* or a *Patch* as arguments, how could you create a geometry formed by several Polygons? It would be something like a `plt.MultiPolygon()`, but that doesn't exist. I've tried to create a `matplotlib.PatchCollection` with all the Polygons, but that does not work.

Here is the desired goal (from upper to lower figure):
[image]

Here is how I'd like the **code** to look like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

points = np.array([np.random.random(100)*400,
                    np.random.random(100)*100]).T

A = plt.Polygon( np.array([( 0,   0),(50,100),(100,  0)]), color='w', ec='k' )
B = plt.Polygon( np.array([(120 ,  0),(170 , 100), (220,  0)]), color='w', ec='k'  )
C = plt.Polygon( np.array([(240 ,  0),(290 , 100), (340,  0)]), color='w', ec='k'  )

[ax.add_patch(i) for i in (A,B,C)]

ax.scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1], zorder=3).set_clip_path([A,B,C])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate the `vertices` and the `codes` of all polygons, and use them to create a ["compound path"](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/path_tutorial.html#compound-paths). [Matplotlib's path tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/path_tutorial.html) contains an example creating a histogram from just one compound path.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
import numpy as np

points = np.array([np.random.random(100) * 400,
                   np.random.random(100) * 100]).T
A = plt.Polygon(np.array([(0, 0), (50, 100), (100, 0)]), color='w', ec='k')
B = plt.Polygon(np.array([(120, 0), (170, 100), (220, 0)]), color='w', ec='k')
C = plt.Polygon(np.array([(240, 0), (290, 100), (340, 0)]), color='w', ec='k')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
all_polys = [A, B, C]
[ax.add_patch(i) for i in all_polys]
vertices = np.concatenate([i.get_path().vertices for i in all_polys])
codes = np.concatenate([i.get_path().codes for i in all_polys])

dots = ax.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], zorder=3)
dots.set_clip_path(PathPatch(Path(vertices, codes), transform=ax.transData))
plt.show()
```

[image: clipping by multiple polygons]

Comment: Wow, it works completely great! Thank you very much.
And it's also possible to apply it to a matplotlib.collection (once it's first created).